# $L^p$ norm and integral equality prove

Tags: measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrate and measure problem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156878/integrate-and-measure-problem)

Assume $\mu(X)=1$, $f \in L^{p} (X,M,\mu)$ for some $0<p \le \infty$

I want to prove that:
$$\lim_{p\to 0}||f||_p = e^{\int_X \log|f|d \mu}$$

I'm going to prove $\ge$ part using Jensen inequality, but I cannot go opposite side. How can I make it?

Comment: The discrete (finite) version of this statement can be shown directly by continuity of exponentiation and l'Hospital rule, but I'm not sure how to generalize it to arbitrary spaces.

Comment: [The same question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/156878/8271)

Answer (score 2):

*(I didn't have time to consider the case $\int_X\log|f|=-\infty$, so I post what I have)*

Assume first that $\int_X\log|f|\,d\mu$ is finite.

Using that $\mu(X)=1$, that $p$ can be assumed small, and Taylor approximations around $0$ for $\log(1+t)$, $e^t$ (i.e. $\log(1+t)\simeq t$, $e^t\simeq1+t$),
$$
e^{\int_X\log|f|\,d\mu}=\lim_{p\to0}e^{\frac1p\int_Xp\log|f|}=\lim_{p\to0}e^{\frac1p\log\left(1+\int_Xp\log|f|\right)}=\lim_{p\to0}\left(1+\int_Xp\log|f|\right)^{1/p}
=\lim_{p\to0}\left(\int_X1+p\log|f|\right)^{1/p}
=\lim_{p\to0}\left(\int_Xe^{p\log|f|}\right)^{1/p}\\
=\lim_{p\to0}\left(\int_X{|f|^p}\,\right)^{1/p}
=\lim_{p\to0}\|f\|_p.
$$

In the case where $\int_X\log|f|\,d\mu=\infty$, then $\|f\|_p=\infty$ for all $p$ and so the equality holds. Indeed, if $\|f\|_p<\infty$ for some $p$, using that there exists $k>0$ such that $\log t\leq t^p$ if $t>k$, we get
$$
\int_X\log|f|=\int_{|f|\leq k}\log|f|+\int_{|f|>k}\log|f|\leq\log k + \int_{|f|>k}|f|^p\leq\log k +\|f\|_p<\infty.
$$

Comment: I am wondering how to push this to the case $\int_{X}Log|f|=-\infty$. But the other post solved this issue.